# ImportError: `load_model` requires h5py when loading hdf5

Tags: python, keras

I saved Keras model in `hdf5` format as follows:

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
filepath="keras_ltsm_dep_model2.hdf5"
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, 
                               monitor='val_acc',
                               verbose=1,
                               save_best_only=True,
                               mode='max')
```

Then I tried to load this model in another program as follows:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('keras_ltsm_arr_model_081.hdf5')
```

Then I got the following error:

```
ImportError: `load_model` requires h5py
```

How should I load my model saved in `hdf5` format?

Comment: Have you tried installing hdf5py ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install `h5py` lib?

Try this:

1. `sudo apt-get install libhdf5`
2. `sudo pip install h5py`

If it's not working, maybe you also need to install `cython` as well (you can check if you already have it). If it happens, do: `sudo pip install cython`

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I also changed the versions of Keras and Tensorflow, so that it's the same in the machine where I saved the mode and in the machine where I load the model.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after downgrading Tensorflow and Keras (on a Windows machine). Simply uninstalling h5py and reinstalling h5py solved the issue (seems that a matching version was required).

```
pip uninstall h5py
pip install h5py
```